# Android achartEngine how to highlight particular chart element

Tags: android, achartengine, pie-chart

Hi i am using achartengine's pie-chart  to represent my actual sales, now  as my app starts one of the chart element in the piechart should get highlighted, like when we do the  onclick on pie chart.

Below is the code for my piechart

```
final DefaultRenderer renderer = buildCategoryRenderer(colors);
       renderer.setPanEnabled(false);// Disable User Interaction
       renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
       renderer.setShowLegend(true);
       renderer.setLegendTextSize(20);
       renderer.setInScroll(true);
       renderer.setStartAngle(180);

     renderer.setChartTitle("Sales By Market Segment- Month");
       renderer.setLabelsTextSize(22);
      final CategorySeries categorySeries = new CategorySeries("Sales");
       categorySeries.add("Craft1",  cursor.getInt(1));
             categorySeries.add("product1", cursor.getInt(2) );
              categorySeries.add("product2",  cursor.getInt(3) );
              categorySeries.add("product",  cursor.getInt(4));
              categorySeries.add("product1", cursor.getInt(5));

      mChartView2=ChartFactory.getPieChartView(context, categorySeries,renderer);
      parent.addView(mChartView2);
      renderer.setClickEnabled(true);
      mChartView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView2.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
              if (seriesSelection == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No chart element selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
              }else {
                  for (int i = 0; i < categorySeries.getItemCount(); i++) {
                      renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i).setHighlighted(i == seriesSelection.getPointIndex());
                    }
                  mChartView2.repaint();
                    Toast.makeText(
                        getActivity(),
                        "Chart data point index " + seriesSelection.getPointIndex() + " selected"
                            + " point value=" + seriesSelection.getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
                }
              });
      return ChartFactory.getPieChartIntent(context, categorySeries, renderer,null);
     }
     protected DefaultRenderer buildCategoryRenderer(int[] colors) {
      DefaultRenderer renderer = new DefaultRenderer();
      for (int color : colors) {
      SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
      r.setColor(color);
      renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);

      }
      return renderer;
      }
```

products are getting highlighted when clicking but I want to highlight one product, when app starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
 mChartView2=ChartFactory.getPieChartView(context, categorySeries,renderer);
      parent.addView(mChartView2);
      renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(0).setHighlighted(true);
      mChartView2.repaint();
```